# adding toolbox components to c# graphics

Tags: c#, graphics

i want to add normal toolbox buttons to my windows form application which overrides the onpaint method of form to change the shape of form to oval. when i add the code of creating new buttons int the load event there is no visible effect at all, i dont see any button.

please assist me in how to use graphics along with the normal controls.

i am pasting the code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace gadget2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[] b = new Button[3];
        GraphicsPath shape = new GraphicsPath();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        { 
            shape.AddEllipse(50, 50, 200, 200);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(shape);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                b[i] = new Button();
                b[i].AutoSize = false;
                b[i].Width = 100;
                b[i].Height = 100;
                b[i].Location = new Point(255, 70 + i * 30);
                this.Controls.Add(b[i]);
                b[i].Show();
                b[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
                b[i].BringToFront();
            }  
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mayank");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mayank");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mayank");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Assigning the Region property in the Paint event is fundamentally wrong, do it in the constructor instead.  You can't see the buttons because you gave them the wrong Location property, X is too large.

Comment: @ Hans Passant , sir if i even set the Location.X property of button to 10 or to even 0 it doesnt show up,not just the button but the whole form itself.Infact if i run the code as it is here, i get no output atall as if there is no application running(just the taskbar icon of application is visible). when i comment all the form_load (button part) then i get the output as a blank oval form, without any buttons.